# VariableSizedWrapGrid Collapsed item not gone Completely

Tags: uwp

I have some tile im my UWP app that should be Wrap if not exist space I used `VariableSizedWrapGrid` but if I set the `Visibility` of one tile to `Collapse` it's hidden but its space remains, can do this work with`VariableSizedWrapGrid` or have anyone a solution for this?

Comment: xaml ?...............

Answer (score 0):

StackPanel behaves the way you desire, for VariableSizedWrapGrid, you may need to remove the child element from the Children collection in order to reclaim the space it occupies (and you can insert it into the collection again to show it).

Comment: I needed to use `VariableSizedWrapGrid` in my app, you're right, it worked by removing but is there a way to solve this issue without removing and only `Collapsing` the item?

Comment: I don’t know, but it is designed to work more like a Grid than an StackPanel, with Grid, you can put elements into specific cells, but the Grid doesn’t rearrange its children’s position if some of them are hidden, it just arrange the children once. It is a special kind of Grid that some elements can occupy more than one cell, and it auto wraps to the next row or column, thus the name “VariableSizedWrapGrid”.